# Hide parent elements when routed to child in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

So I have a parent component `tours`, which has a list. When clicked on a list item it routes to `/tours/tour-one`, that is to the details of that particular tour.

My issue: when the detail is routed, I would like all the elements of the parent compontent(`tours`) not to be visible in the view. Initially I had done this whole master-detail view with `ngIf` and `services` but now I am forced to use Routing, which is also better, but I am unable to get the desired UI.

Here is my `tours.component.html`:

```html
<div class="tours-left">
      <div class="tours-info main-text">
        <div class="tours-list-wrapper">
          <div class="tours-thumbs">
            <div class="tour-container" [routerLink]="['/tours', tour.sys.id]" *ngFor="let tour of toursThumbs">
              <figure class="tour-image">
                <picture>
                  <img
                  src="{{ tour.fields.tourCoverPhoto.fields.tourCoverPhoto.fields.file.url }}"
                  alt="{{ tour.fields.tourCoverPhoto.fields.tourCoverPhoto.fields.description }}"
                  title="{{ tour.fields.tourCoverPhoto.fields.tourCoverPhoto.fields.title }}"
                  [target]="tourBackgroundImg" dynamicBackgroundImg />
                  <figcaption><span>{{ tour.fields.tourTitle }}</span></figcaption>
                </picture>
              </figure>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
```

From the HTML, I would like to have everything within `div.tours-list-wrapper` to be hidden or removed from the DOM when url is at `tours/<tour detail>`

Any input is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you need to replace the details page with the list page.

If you have the root `router-outlet` in the App Component, then you can just remove the  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from you code and it should work as you want. Angular will replace the whole page with the new one.